# How can I do a backslash in Spanish keyboard using ubuntu

Tags: keyboard

I was trying several ways of doing backslash in ubuntu using alt + shift + u 
didn't work
or ctrl + alt + 92 
neither work 
what could be a trust way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

Try with : "ALT Gr" + the "?"

It may depend of course of your keyboard distribution(not all spanish keyboards have the same)

But as suggestion, the Ctrl + Alt thing of windows looks like works only with the "ALT GR" key. It should be in the right side of the space bar.

I have the "?" sign at the right of the "0(zero)" so you could try that way if you dont see the \ in that key.

Comment: It did not work for me.  :(